# What this reg expression mean

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not good in regex. I have to read some code with very poor documentation can anyone please tell what is the meaning of this regular expression or line of code

```
myid.replace(/(:|\.)/g,'\\\\$1');
```

Please tell the meaning of this reg ex ??

Comment: Please show *some* effort. [Here is a good tutorial.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: sorry but time constraint i also feeling little weired about asking this question but thanks a lot

Comment: There are many websites that can answer any "what does this regex do" question - http://regex101.com/, http://www.regexplained.co.uk/, http://crotonresearch.com/graphrex/

Comment: @maerics to be fair, they don't cover the replacement string ;)

Comment: @m.buettner: heh, true =|

Comment: @maerics there is a banner at the top of that site saying to let the site owner know about any features you would like to see.

Answer (score 6):

It matches any number of `.` or `:` and adds `\\` before them..

So, if it matches `.`, it would replace it to `\\.`

---

When you use `()` it represents a [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) and you can refer the value captured inside it using backreference `$n` where n is the group number..

`g` is a [flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) which performs global match i.e in your case it would replace all occurances of `.` or `:`

Without `g` flag it would replace only the first occurance of `.` or `:`